# Symfony assetic css file changes doesn't apear

Tags: css, symfony, less, assetic

I use assetic to compile less file in my symfony project, less files compiles with no error but generated css file **(../web/app_dev.php/css/XXX.css)** is same as before !

But when I check actual genereated file from direct url **(../web/css/XXX.css)** every thing is ok and all changes performed.

`php console cache:clear` did not help.

Comment: Have you  tried to clear your browser's cache?

Comment: ( **clearing browser cache**  + **php console cache:clear** ) solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear your browser's cache AND your Symfony cache.

Browser's cache (expecially with Chrome) can be really aggresssive, and don't aknowledge immediately the changes.